# Flutter Local Database does not working on real ios device

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter app using sqflite database. It perfectly works on IOS emulator. But on real ios device it doesn't open page and gives error below. It gives some error with local db but I don't really get why it works on Simulator but not on real physical device.

[image: Error]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import '../models/task.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database? _db;
  static final int _version = 1;
  static final String _tableName = 'tasks';

  static Future<void> initDb() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      debugPrint("not null db");
      return;
    }
    try {
      String _path = await getDatabasesPath() + 'tasks.db';
      debugPrint("in database path");
      _db = await openDatabase(
        _path,
        version: _version,
        onCreate: (db, version) {
          debugPrint("creating a new one");
          return db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE $_tableName("
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                "title STRING, note TEXT, date STRING, "
                "startTime STRING, endTime STRING, "
                "remind INTEGER, repeat STRING, "
                "color INTEGER, "
                "isCompleted INTEGER)",
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static Future<int> insert(Task task) async {
    print("insert function called");
    return await _db!.insert(_tableName, task.toJson());
  }
  static Future<int> delete(Task task) async =>
      await _db!.delete(_tableName, where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [task.id]);

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> query() async {
    print("query function called");
    return _db!.query(_tableName);
  }
  static Future<int> update(int? id) async {
    print("update function called");
    return await _db!.rawUpdate('''
    UPDATE tasks   
    SET isCompleted = ?
    WHERE id = ?
    ''', [1, id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `getDatabasesPath` defined and where does it guarantee it always returns a path with a trailing slash? Also, you're using `!` a lot in your code, which is a code-smell: _why_ is your `_db` field nullable?

Comment: ...why does your `update` function accept a nullable `int? id` value? Your `UPDATE` statement won't work with `null` values because the `=` operator in SQL always fails for `NULL`s (hence the `IS [NOT] NULL` and `IS DISTINCT FROM` operators).

Comment: Hey, i just got this code from a freelance developer, and now he is not available. can you please help me solve it?